# Desconsiderar o cabeçalho de um arquivo .csv na hora de importar para o banco de dados

Tags: c#

Preciso na hora de ler um arquivo .csv desconsiderar o cabeçalho na hora de importar para o banco de dados como é possivel ?

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine(); 

campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);

registro = dt.NewRow();
```

Comment: Mostre parte do seu código que você está usando para importar e lhe diremos como altera-lo de modo a atingir seu objetivo.

Comment: Então Gustavo no meu código ele ta lendo o arquivo inteiro , a primeira linha que é o cabeçalho também , nao estou conseguindo com que ele NÂO leia a primeira linha...tem alguma idéia ?

Comment: linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine();
                    campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    registro = dt.NewRow();

Comment: Ai assim ele ta lendo todas as linhas

Comment: Este código deve estar dentro de um loop que itera entre as linhas do arquivo. Apenas ignore a primeira iteração (adicionando um if abaixo de `linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine();`). Sugiro depurar o código linha a linha para enteder como ele funciona.

Comment: Sim ele esta dentro desse while (!arquivo.EndOfStream) , beleza vou tentar isso agora !

Comment: Postei uma resposta sugerindo uma maneira de fazer este IF.

Comment: certo obrigado ! o meu loop eu mantenho entao ne ?  while (!arquivo.EndOfStream)

Comment: Caffé é isso ai consegui desconsiderar o cabeçalho muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Legal, Daniel. Da próxima vez já vá logo mostrando o código e considere aceitar a resposta se resolveu o seu problema - tudo isso faz desta ferramenta aqui um lugar mais bacana.

Comment: Certo pode deixar , e ja aceitei a resposta, é a minha primeira vez aqui valeu

Comment: Daniel, para complementar, você poderia incluir o seu código "completo" (com o `while`) na questão, para que fique mais claro para os próximos que tiverem a mesma dúvida que você.

Comment: Então o problema eh que ele ultrapassa os limites de caracteres

Comment: comprimento excedido em 2637 caracteres

Comment: using (StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader(caminho))
{
string linhaArquivo;
string[] campos;
DataRow registro;
bool cabecalhoJaLido = false;

while (!arquivo.EndOfStream)
{
                    
linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine();

if (!cabecalhoJaLido)
{
cabecalhoJaLido = true;
continue;
}
                   
campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
registro = dt.NewRow();

Comment: registro["Nome"] = campos[0].ToString().Trim();
registro["Documento"] = campos[1].Trim().ToString();
registro["Endereco"] = campos[3].Trim().ToString();
registro["Complemento"] = campos[5].Trim().ToString();
registro["Bairro"] = campos[6].Trim().ToString();
registro["Cidade"] = campos[8].Trim().ToString();
registro["CEP"] = campos[9].Trim().ToString();
registro["Numero"] = Convert.ToInt32(campos[4]);
registro["TipoPessoa"] = Convert.ToInt32(campos[2]);
registro["Estado"] = Convert.ToInt32(campos[7]); dt.Rows.Add(registro);
}
return dt;

Comment: Daniel, vi teus novos comentários sem querer. Não adianta pedir por mais ajuda nos comentários desta pergunta. Me parece que o problema que você tinha quando postou esta pergunta foi resolvido. Crie agora uma nova pergunta com seus novos problemas, mostrando todo o código relevante, a linha que dá o erro e a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: Caffé ele foi resolvido mesmo ta tudo certo...Eu estava falando com a Beterraba que pediu para que me postasse o codigo inteiro mas ele excede o limite de caracteres entendeu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código deve estar dentro de um loop que itera entre as linhas do arquivo.

Apenas ignore a primeira iteração adicionando um if abaixo de `linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine()`:

```
bool cabecalhoJaLido = false;

for ... // você não postou o código que mostra o loop.

    linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine(); 

    if (!cabecalhoJaLido) {
        cabecalhoJaLido = true;
        continue;
    }

    campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, 
        StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Mais eficiente ler o cabeçalho antes do `for` :)

Comment: @Beterraba Tão eficiente quanto. Apenas menos linhas. Não é um IF bool que fará diferença na eficiência :-) Mas concordo que seria melhor. Faz tempo que não programo e nem tenho nenhuma IDE aqui. Meio enferrujado...

Comment: @Beterraba De qualquer modo, ao ler o cabeçalho antes de entrar no loop, teria que encontrar um meio de fazê-lo sem depender de um comentário do tipo `arquivo.ReadLine(); // ignora o cabeçalho`. Defendo que o código tem que ser auto explicativo e este aí apesar de mais linhas, é bem claro :-)

Comment: Mas comentários fazem parte do código hahaha! Foi só pra apontar a possibilidade de se ignorar a linha antes do `for`. É como eu faria e achei interessante compartilhar.

Comment: @Beterraba Aí eu discordo totalmente. Comentário faz parte apenas do código que não teve sucesso em ser um bom código.

Comment: Prefiro um comentário que um `if` desnecessário. Apesar de sua afirmação ter seus méritos, eu discordo da generalização excessiva. Mas, de novo, apenas questão de gosto. Não quero polemizar!

Comment: @Beterraba É, este assunto é sempre uma longa discussão; que eu gosto muito, inclusive :D Mas de fato aqui não é o lugar adequado.